# How to query a JSONB column that has deeply nested objects in Python/FastAPI, SqlAlchemy, and PostgreSQL

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, fastapi

In a PostgreSQL table "private_notion", I have a JSONB column "record_map" that may or may not contain nested objects, E.g.

```
{
  "blocks": {
    "7a9abf0d-a066-4466-a565-4e6d7a960a37": {
      "name": "block1",
      "value": 1,
      "child": {
        "7a9abf0d-a066-4466-a565-4e6d7a960a37": {
          "name": "block2",
          "value": 2,
          "child": {
            "7a9abf0d-a066-4466-a565-4e6d7a960a37": {
              "name": "block3",
              "value": 3
            }
          }
        },
        "7a9abf0d-a066-4466-a565-4e6d7a960a38": {
          "name": "block4",
          "value": 4,
          "child": {
            "7a9abf0d-a066-4466-a565-4e6d7a960a39": {
              "name": "block5",
              "value": 5,
              "child": {
                "7a9abf0d-a066-4466-a565-4e6d7a960a40": {
                  "name": "block6",
                  "value": 6
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
      }
    }
  }
}
```

To retrieve data, We don't know which block has the data we want, we only have the key. Let's assume we are looking for the object with this key "7a9abf0d-a066-4466-a565-4e6d7a960a40", but we don't know that it is located in child block6 of parent block4 and block5. Another request might look for the parent block4 and so on, and I must find the block by it's key.

The entire code looks like this;

```
async def get_private_notion_page(
        site_uuid: str, page_id: str, db_session: AsyncSession
    ) -> PrivateNotionPage:
       
        page_id_path = f"{page_id}" # page_id looks like this 7a9abf0d-a066-4466-a565-4e6d7a960a37
        path = f"$.** ? (@.{page_id_path})"

        stmt = text(
            f"""
            SELECT jsonb_path_query(record_map, {path})
            FROM private_notion
            WHERE site_id = {site_uuid}
            """
        )

        result = await db_session.execute(stmt)
        result = result.scalars().first()

        if result:
            return result
        else:
            raise PrivateNotionSiteWasNotFound
```

So I came up with the following query statements which use sqlalchemy "text" method to accept raw SQL query, but `jsonb_path_query_array` and `jsonb_path_query` throw similar errors; `syntax error at or near "$"`.

```
page_id_path = f"{page_id}"
path = f"$.** ? (@.{page_id_path})"
stmt = text(
            f"""
            SELECT jsonb_path_query(record_map, {path})
            FROM private_notion
            WHERE site_id = {site_uuid}
            """
        )

Error:

sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.asyncpg.ProgrammingError) <class 'asyncpg.exceptions.PostgresSyntaxError'>: syntax error at or near "$"
[SQL: 
             SELECT jsonb_path_query(record_map, $.** ? (@.7a9abf0d-a066-4466-a565-4e6d7a960a37))
             FROM private_notion
             WHERE site_id = 26f52d8e-a380-46ab-9131-e6f7f62c528f
]
```

I would later learn that "The $** operator is not valid in a SQL query. Instead, you can use the jsonb_path_query_array function to search recursively through all levels of the JSONB object."

Apparently I got the same error after refactoring the code.

```
page_id_path = f"{page_id}"
path = f"$[*] ? (@ like_regex {page_id_path})"
stmt = text(
            f"""
            SELECT jsonb_path_query_array(record_map -> 'block', {path})
            FROM private_notion
            WHERE site_id = {site_uuid}
            """
        )

Error:

sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.asyncpg.ProgrammingError) <class 'asyncpg.exceptions.PostgresSyntaxError'>: syntax error at or near "$"
[SQL: 
     SELECT jsonb_path_query_array(record_map -> 'block', $[*] ? (@ like_regex 7a9abf0d-a066-4466-a565-4e6d7a960a37))
     FROM private_notion
     WHERE site_id = 26f52d8e-a380-46ab-9131-e6f7f62c528f
]
```

My question is two-pronged, what is the error all about? And is there a better way to retrieve a nested object by key in a JSONB column? Thank you for your time.

Comment: JSONPath expression needs to be single-quoted: `SELECT jsonb_path_query(record_map, '$.** ? (@.7a9abf0d-a066-4466-a565-4e6d7a960a37)') FROM private_notion`

Comment: Thanks @Zegarek you are correct. It solves this particular issue but i still haven't gotten the query right with the statement above. Would i have to accept this as the answer, and ask another question for the query?

Comment: Sure, that would make sense. You could edit leave this thread focused on the syntactic issues and prepare the new one to only address the problem of constructing the right JSONPath to get the right results - make sure to add some mock samples and explain what exactly you're trying to extract out of them, in what format, with/without what additional content of the json value.

Comment: I did mention that I want to retrieve an object at any nested level by its key. And it appears you've done just that in the last 2 examples here https://dbfiddle.uk/XIC--gGf.  Please include the last 2 examples so i can accept the answer. I'm so grateful, thank you.

Comment: That works too. I've added the last one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This extracts entire objects at any level that have your target uuid-based key in them: [demo at db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/BFVlMgmJ)

```sql
SELECT jsonb_path_query(record_map, 
                        'strict $.**?(@.keyvalue().key==$target_id)',
                        jsonb_build_object('target_id',
                                           '7a9abf0d-a066-4466-a565-4e6d7a960a37'))
FROM private_notion
WHERE site_id = '45bf37be-ca0a-45eb-838b-015c7a89d47b';
```

| jsonb_path_query |
| --- |
| { "7a9abf0d-a066-4466-a565-4e6d7a960a37": { "name": "block1", "child": { "7a9abf0d-a066-4466-a565-4e6d7a960a37": { "name": "block2", "child": { "7a9abf0d-a066-4466-a565-4e6d7a960a37": { "name": "block3", "value": 3 } }, "value": 2 }, "7a9abf0d-a066-4466-a565-4e6d7a960a38": { "name": "block4", "child": { "7a9abf0d-a066-4466-a565-4e6d7a960a39": { "name": "block5", "child": { "7a9abf0d-a066-4466-a565-4e6d7a960a40": { "name": "block6", "value": 6 } }, "value": 5 } }, "value": 4 } }, "value": 1 } } |
| { "7a9abf0d-a066-4466-a565-4e6d7a960a37": { "name": "block2", "child": { "7a9abf0d-a066-4466-a565-4e6d7a960a37": { "name": "block3", "value": 3 } }, "value": 2 }, "7a9abf0d-a066-4466-a565-4e6d7a960a38": { "name": "block4", "child": { "7a9abf0d-a066-4466-a565-4e6d7a960a39": { "name": "block5", "child": { "7a9abf0d-a066-4466-a565-4e6d7a960a40": { "name": "block6", "value": 6 } }, "value": 5 } }, "value": 4 } } |
| { "7a9abf0d-a066-4466-a565-4e6d7a960a37": { "name": "block3", "value": 3 } } |

Note the object duplication through unnesting: they appear both alone as well as inside each matched parent structure.

1. JSONPath expression needs to be single-quoted. This gets rid of the syntax error:

   ```
   ERROR:  syntax error at or near "$"
   LINE 2:                         $.**.7a9abf0d-a066-4466-a565-4e6d7a9...
                                   ^
   ```
2. Your uuid-based key inside the JSONPath needs to be double-quoted. This will get rid of a problem inside the expression that would soon follow:

   ```
   ERROR:  trailing junk after numeric literal at or near ".7a" of jsonpath input
   LINE 2:                         '$.**.7a9abf0d-a066-4466-a565-4e6d7a...
                                   ^
   ```
3. When using `.**` accessor, default to using [`strict` mode](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#STRICT-AND-LAX-MODES).
4. You can use the [SQLAlchemy JSONPath type](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/dialects/postgresql.html#sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.JSONPATH) to pass the expression.

Comment: Thank you. Is it possible to retrieve the object with the key? 
E.g. ` "7a9abf0d-a066-4466-a565-4e6d7a960a39": {"name": "block3", "value": 3} `

Comment: Sure, why not? [Here are some additional examples at the end](https://dbfiddle.uk/kmK184qX)